# compile completed but can not excute with error "no such file or directory" in ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compilation

I compile a short file named `myfile.c` with `gcc` compiler like:

```
$ gcc myfile.c -o myapp
```

everything is ok and I run it by:

```
$ ./myapp
```

and what I've got:

```
No such file or directory.
```

When I  `ls`, myapp is still there on the screen, just I can not run it. But some other files I've compiled still working normally. I've even removed some execute files and compiled them again and it's smooth working, so I guess the problem is in myfile.c.

The question is: why the file exist after compiling, but the kernel can not realize it with the alert "no such file or directory".

The myfile.c I've copy from beej.us for learning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                    /* l_type   l_whence  l_start  l_len  l_pid   */
    struct flock fl = {F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET,   0,      0,     0 };
    int fd;

    fl.l_pid = getpid();

    if (argc > 1) 
        fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;

    if ((fd = open("lockdemo.c", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Press <RETURN> to try to get lock: ");
    getchar();
    printf("Trying to get lock...");

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("got lock\n");
    printf("Press <RETURN> to release lock: ");
    getchar();

    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;  /* set to unlock same region */

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Unlocked.\n");

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error message is not: `open: No such file or directory` ? If it is then that error message is coming from the line: `perror("open");` - probably because you have no file `lockdemo.c`.

Comment: may be i have not create lockdemo.c. I have never created it before so i must check again. thank u so much and please take my kiss too.